# grep to show things in the same file together

Tags: grep

When I do grep in this way on multiple files, I have:

```
$ grep "Sh\|Re" To_10pair_20140708_20160704_TIR_2.4_TSR_2.4_TP_1.0_SP_1.0/*/key_re*
To_10pair_20140708_20160704_TIR_2.4_TSR_2.4_TP_1.0_SP_1.0/QTNNSimplePredict_HLD_100,100_DOI_12_PG_12_WD_1e-05_SOT_10pair_20090601_20140707/key_results.txt:Sharpe ratio is: -1.6022503031
To_10pair_20140708_20160704_TIR_2.4_TSR_2.4_TP_1.0_SP_1.0/QTNNSimplePredict_HLD_100,100_DOI_12_PG_12_WD_1e-05_SOT_10pair_20090601_20140707/key_results.txt:Return rate is: -0.2357384
To_10pair_20140708_20160704_TIR_2.4_TSR_2.4_TP_1.0_SP_1.0/QTNNSimplePredict_HLD_100,100_DOI_12_PG_12_WD_4e-05_SOT_10pair_20090601_20140707/key_results.txt:Sharpe ratio is: 0.822358458311
To_10pair_20140708_20160704_TIR_2.4_TSR_2.4_TP_1.0_SP_1.0/QTNNSimplePredict_HLD_100,100_DOI_12_PG_12_WD_4e-05_SOT_10pair_20090601_20140707/key_results.txt:Return rate is: -0.0432811
```

Is it possible to have the result looks like

```
To_10pair_20140708_20160704_TIR_2.4_TSR_2.4_TP_1.0_SP_1.0/QTNNSimplePredict_HLD_100,100_DOI_12_PG_12_WD_1e-05_SOT_10pair_20090601_20140707/key_results.txt:
Sharpe ratio is: -1.6022503031
Return rate is: -0.2357384
To_10pair_20140708_20160704_TIR_2.4_TSR_2.4_TP_1.0_SP_1.0/QTNNSimplePredict_HLD_100,100_DOI_12_PG_12_WD_4e-05_SOT_10pair_20090601_20140707/key_results.txt:
Sharpe ratio is: 0.822358458311
Return rate is: -0.0432811
```

Answer (score 3):

You could pipe the result to sed:

```
grep ...key_re* | sed -e '/:Sharpe/{h;s/:.*/:/;p;g;}' -e 's/[^:]*://'
```

Comment: how do you come out of this?

Comment: @VacassalAlsk: I don't understand your question.